# Is Verbatim or escaping the preferred way to deal with quote-rich strings in C#?

Tags: c#, string, escaping, zebra-printers, verbatim-string

To escape or to verbatim, that is my question.

I need to programmatically send a couple of commands to a (Zebra QLn220) printer in C#, specifically:

```
! U1 setvar "power.dtr_power_off" "off"
```

-and:

```
! U1 setvar "media.sense_mode" "gap"
```

Due to the plethora of quotes in these commands, I thought it would be sensible to use verbatim strings. But based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx), I still need to double the quotes, so that it would presumably/theoretically need to be like:

```
string dontShutErOff = @"! U1 setvar """power.dtr_power_off""" """off"""";
```

...which looks like a mashup composed of [Don King](http://www.tr3s.com/music/artists/justin-bieber/photos/iconic-hair-don-king/?flipbook=iconic-celebrity-hairstyles), the [cat from Coding Horror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/), and [Groucho Marx](http://cdn1.galadarling.com/images/08-04/groucho.jpg).

Would it be better to escape the quotes this way:

```
string dontShutErOff = "! U1 setvar \"power.dtr_power_off\" \"off\"";
```

?

Should I Escape from Verbatimtraz?

### UPDATE

Based on Eric Lippert's first suggestion, how about this:

```
const string quote = "\"";
string whatever = string.Format("! U1 setvar {0}power.dtr_power_off{0} {0}off{0}", quote);
```

Comment: Escaping correctly is more important: in verbatim, `""`, not `"""`, is the escaped version of `"`.

Comment: 2 upvotes and 3 close votes; that seems an odd juxtaposition

Comment: I suggested a [feature](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/workitem/62) to deal with usecases like this. I don't think any of the current methods are satisfactory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would consider a third alternative:

```
const string quote = "\"";
string whatever = "! U1 setvar " + 
                  quote + "power.dtr_power_off" + quote + " " +
                  quote + "off" + quote;
```

Or a fourth:

```
static string Quote(string x) 
{
    const string quote = "\""; 
    return quote + x + quote;
}
...
string whatever = "! U1 setvar " + Quote("power.dtr_power_off") + " " + Quote("off");
```

All these have pros and cons; none is clearly the best.

Comment: What is the reason for putting `const` on the `quote` variable? I can see it's generating different IL codes then a non-const string variable, but I'm not sure why or what the difference is.

Comment: What do you think about my take on your first take (in my Update above)?

Comment: @asawyer Making the variable `const` means that the compiler will do a straight in-source substitution, at which point the compiler's constant-folding logic will ensure that the final string is completely formed at compile-time, rather than forcing run-time concatenation.

Answer (score 5):

Resources may be better approach - it looks like you planning to have C# constants to have names anyway.Let resource auto-generation to create C# constant for you while editing commands as regular text.

Comment: If I had a bunch of these, I guess; but for just two, using resource strings seems like putting on a tie to tie your tennies.

Answer (score 2):

Verbatim strings don't allow double quotes as you've described in your first example. It won't compile.

I juts found this out actually... It does support double-double quotes as quotes. So your first example would look like this:

```
string dontShutErOff = @"! U1 setvar ""power.dtr_power_off"" ""off""";
```

However, if your string literals are important, won't likely change, or may need to be translated in the future, I would put them in a resource file as mentioned in a previous answer. Any escaping is done automatically and the string is easily readable.

Comment: Thanks; BTW, is your name Scot Campbell, or Scamp Bell?

Comment: No problem. Stack Overflow users have profile sections with names and other information like that. You're closer on the first one though :)

Comment: Your profile simply says "Scampbell," so...it *is* a problem ;-)

Comment: Good to know. I thought all of that was public. It's Sam Campbell.

Answer (score 1):

Your first line should be:

```
string dontShutErOff = @"! U1 setvar ""power.dtr_power_off"" ""off""";
```

Quotation marks are written as double quotation marks, not triple.

Neither way is clearly better than the other, at least not for quotation marks. It's mostly a matter of taste. In other situations one way or the other has clear advantages, for example using a @ delimited string for file paths that contain backslashes.